# Почему мультизадачность уменьшает общее время выполнения?

Tags: процессор

В кое-какой книге я вычитал, что мультизадачность позволяет ускорить процесс выполнения нескольких задач. У меня возникла пара вопросов.

Инструкции на однопроцессорной машине выполняются строго последовательно. Мультизадачность заключается в том, что каждой задаче поочерёдно передаётся управление на небольше время, в следствие чего создаётся ощущение их одновременной работы, однако суммарное время выполнения каждой задачи, участвующей в борьбе за процессорное время, равно времени, за которое эта же задача выполнилась бы без перерывов. А значит, мультизадачность не только не может ускорять процесс, но и замедляет его, т.к. переключение между задачами занимает дополнительное время. Этот тезис основан мной на теории, приведённой в той же самой книге, упомянутой мной вначале.

Есть ощущения, что я что-то где-то не понял, из-за чего теперь в голове конфуз. Не могу сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы он мог быть "переварен" поисковиком, не обессудьте.

Comment: а что если одна задача ждет ввода-вывода? почему бы в это время не просто ждать а сделать что-то полезное?

Comment: У нас тут в 2019 году в каждом процессоре по 8-16 ядер стоит, да ещё и с гипертредингом ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отвлекитесь от технологий, обратите внимание на приготовление еды. Если бы варили суп и приступили бы к чистке картофеля лишь после того как закипит вода, то вы бы потеряли время также, как если бы поставили кипять воду после чистки картофеля.

В этом примере кастрюля с водой это некоторое устройство (в вычислителях — это сетевая карта, жёсткий накопитель, видеокарта и т.п.), а повар в данном случае процессор, который дал задание "устройству" и пошёл заниматься другими делами, требующими более деятельного участия в действии (чистка картошки). Вода же закипит и без его помощи. Таким образом при правильном распределении времени на выполнение задач (в том числе за счёт передачи выполнения оных другим устройствам), мы получаем общий выигрыш во времени, чем если бы мы делали всё шаг за шагом.

Comment: спасибо, улыбнули

Comment: Прикольное объяснение), плюсанул

Answer (score 1):

Мультизадачность позволяет более рационально распределить процессорное время в вычислительной системе. То есть при мультизадачности те задачи, которые в данный момент ждут внешних данных и не могут работать, передают процессорное время тем задачам, которые в данный момент имеют данные и могут работать. За счет этого и происходит общий выигрыш в производительности вычислительной системы. Ну а так-то конечно, переключение задач это накладные расходы и переключение задач отнимает часть производительности вычислительной системы. Но на эти накладные расходы идут осознанно, так как общая производительность вычислительной системы увеличивается.

Comment: Однако в высоконагруженных системах накладные расходы настолько высоки, что в итоге используют всё равно один поток, но с развитой асинхронщиной (см. nginx или nodejs например)

Comment: @andreymal nginx и прочие работают поверх ОС, в которой есть 100500 переключаемых задач. В том числе там крутится куча процессов доступа к сети, к диску и прочие. Так что говорить об одном потоке не приходится. Иногда однозадачные системы делают во встроенных системах на ОЧЕНЬ слабых процессорах. Да и то сейчас все больше и больше во встроенных системах тупо ставят Линукс и пользуются всеми преимуществами многозадачности.

Comment: Я имею в виду один поток в одном отдельно взятом приложении, а вы до абсурда доводите)

Comment: (впрочем, я действительно выразил свою мысль недостаточно чётко)